# update the column of another table using summation result from columns of one table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 columns in one table and need to add these columns rowwise and this result needs to be updated into the column of another table rowwise in postgres.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use a `from` clause in an `update`.  Your question is a bit vague, but something like this:

```
update toupdate
    set sumcol = (t1.col1 + t1.col2 + t1.col3 + t1.col4)
    from table1 t1
    where t1.? = toupdate.?;
```

The `?` is for the columns that identify how rows between the two tables match.